# Finding the dimension of the orthogonal complement

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $U=M_{n}(\mathbb{C})$, and we define a bilinear form $\xi (A,B)=n\cdot tr(AB)-tr(A)tr(B)$. How do I find $dim(U_{\perp })$?

I know that $U_{\perp }=\{A \in M_{n}(\mathbb{C})|\ \forall B\in M_{n}(\mathbb{C}), n\cdot tr(AB)-tr(A)tr(B)=0 \}$. I have no idea how to continue. I'd appreciate any help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Let $A=[a_{i,j}]$ and $B=E_{k,l}$. Then $\xi(A,B)=na_{l,k}-tr(A)\delta_{k,l}=0$. If $k\not= l$, then $a_{l,k}=0$; otherwise, $a_{k,k}=tr(A)/n$. Necessarily, $A$ is a scalar matrix $\lambda I_n$. The converse is clear.